# Build date of bios version - how to check orginality of version ? - used motherboard

Tags: bios, motherboard, secure-boot

I have a used motherboard. Can I make sure that the bios is authentic including the keys (secure bios) ? How can I check it?

For example, the build date of the bios is a few days older than the version on the official manufacturer's website. Do I have grounds for concern?

Is one way to be sure of the motherboard is to flash the bios to e.g. the latest version ?

build date of the bios is a few days older than the version on the official site

// motherboard asus rog strix b660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be worried, since most BIOS versions are
digitally signed, in order to avoid tampering.

You don't specify the make of your motherboard, but it's highly likely
that the BIOS you have was signed with the digital key of the
manufacturer, otherwise it couldn't have been installed in the
first place.

If worried, you could re-flash it with the version on the manufacturer's
website, although this is a dangerous operation where any error can
brick the computer, so not to be carried out lightly.
But check first the version number to see if it's identical
(or higher) than yours. The difference between the dates might
be explainable because of the working procedures of the manufacturer.

Comment: asus rog strix b660 If someone has uploaded some unwanted software (e.g. with a "virus" on it), can it somehow remain on the motherboard? Could it be, for example, some sort of fake secure boot keys?  

I would like to ask whether it is possible to avoid this problem (potential, but it is better to be safe) by a proper installation of the system, e.g. Linux? as far as I know, Linux has its own keys, or in this case it is better to install the system without the secure boot enabled and possibly do something else with it? am i right?

Comment: and btw I see that there are tutorials on how to create your own secure boot keys, but I don't think I have the knowledge or confidence to do it.

Comment: The ASUS ROG STRIX B660 is pretty recent, so surely the BIOS is protected. I don't believe in creating secure boot keys, at least as long as secure boot is enabled (and it should stay enabled).

Comment: But I have a used board and I see some keys there. Could they be dangerous if they have been inserted by a dishonest seller for example?

Comment: Most BIOS today come with several keys, otherwise the main variants of Linux could not be installed.